# Why the parameter TransitRadius in HERE Routing API with public transport do not change the response

Tags: here-api

Trying to use the parameter TransitRaduis in the routing API of HERE. It works well with 'car mode' but when using it with 'public transport' it seems to me that it changes nothing ! 
So setting one waypoint with the following three differents ways, gives the same result !

```
&waypoint0=geo!37.7914050,-122.3987030
&waypoint0=geo!37.7914050,-122.3987030;50
&waypoint0=geo!37.7914050,-122.3987030;500
```

Comment: Could you please share the complete example request?

Answer (score 0):

To request a public transport route using the CalculateRoute service you need to specify a departure time as

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}&waypoint0=geo!52.530,13.326&waypoint1=geo!52.513,13.407&departure=now&mode=fastest;publicTransport&combineChange=true
```

For further details kindly go through the documentation 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-public-transport-routes.html

Good Luck !